# iPhone iOS 12 StackExchange getting disallowed_useragent

Tags: bug, ios-app, stackexchange.com

I have an iPhone on iOS 12. Trying to use StackExchange app  getting disallowed_useragent.

I was on iOS 10 before and everything worked fine.

[image]

Comment: @ArtOfCode This is a different error, though.

Comment: Aye, but I suspect it's the same problem, @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog. It'd be useful to know what happens if Rod logs in via a browser and then tries the app again.

Comment: Wrong app @ArtOfCode. iOS is different, but there's also a dupe.

Comment: I ended up just creating a new stack exchange account and it worked with the app on my iOS 12 device! Hooray!

Comment: You are getting this error because you clicked on "Login with another OpenID", which used to present an OpenID provider picker before that was decommissioned and now presents a general login page.  I will look to see if we can get a better "No longer available" screen in there.

Comment: @ArtOfCode See above comment; it turned out to be a different problem.